# Validate allowed filesize from user input like files to save in local database

Tags: database, validation, input, filesize

I can not allow my user to save a 6 GB video in the sqlite database.

Can I not really? Well all freedom to the user not? Should I protect the user from

himself? Where do I draw the border? 1 mb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show a warning to the user for files above certain size that it would have adverse performance effects. If the user ignores the warning, let them do it. Setting arbitrary hardcoded limits is never a good idea; there will always be that one vocal user that needs to save a slightly bigger than your limit file that will write an angry blog post how bad your app is.